# What are the gains of converting normal method to static?

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods

As it is clear from question, if I convert a normal method to static what gains will I made?

Comment: I'm in a dilemma which one to choose as answers by both Rudolph and Kemp are insightful :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the semantic reasons mentioned above, static methods are generally faster (due to not having to create an object to call the method). They are subject to compile-time optimisations and as far as I recall, the CLR also performs some special optimisations on them.

Comment: I'm choosing this as answer because it seems to give clue about my performance curiosity!

Answer (score 13):

You will gain clarity, because `static` makes it clear that the method doesn’t depend on an object state. You will also facilitate reusability because `static` methods may be used in more contexts (i.e. when you don’t have an instance of the class).

In general, it’s not really a question of gain, it’s a question of semantics: does your method depend on the object state? If so, make it non-`static`. In all other cases, make it `static`.

Comment: I would say you also need to consider discoverability. When someone tries to learn your API via code completion (IntelliSense) it is sometimes easier to find member methods than static methods.

Comment: can you help me with this question please:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791513/what-are-the-desirable-situation-real-life-example-to-create-static-methods-ex

Answer (score 0):

Static function normally used for utility stuffs like `ConverThisTypeToThatType()`, and you can call them without having object of its class.

Ex: `MessageBox.Show("Something");`

here `MessageBox` is a Class and `Show` is static method in it, so we dont need to create object of `MessageBox` to call `Show`.